# Trying to get each Div to appear when it is scrolled to

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a landing page to look a bit more fancy, so when you scroll down the text of each section fades in.

I have it working kind of, but instead of each individual element fading in as you scroll to it, they all fade in at the same time when you scroll to the first element.

I can't quite get my head around where I've gone wrong, I used some code from a jFiddle I found and it works absolutely fine there.

I've tried making the fade in happen individually instead (as ugly as that code looked) but it was still doing the same thing.

```
$(window).scroll( function(){
  $(".hidden-y").each( function(i){

    var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
    var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

    if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
       $(this).addClass("appear");
    }
  });
});
```

I have the elements I want to fade in as they're scrolled to with the class "hidden-y", and when scrolled to I want that element to have the class "appear" to be added. I'm guessing it's adding "appear" to all the elements with the "hidden-y" class, is there an easy way to stop it doing this to all of them at once?

Comment: You should show a [mcve] so we can figure it out

Comment: Your script is working: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/LvWzWo So show us your (full) code, that is not working

Comment: I tried to put one together to replicate the problem I'm having... but it works on codepen. Quite confused. https://codepen.io/KrisMayers/pen/MRpEOG

Comment: Then you should carefully check the differences between the working and the not working situation